# What is the best way to join ordered arrays?

Tags: algorithm

I have few arrays of integers. Elements in each array are ordered. Arrays does not have duplicates.

I need to join all arrays into one so the resulting array contains only elements which exist in every array.

For example, I have arrays

(1,2,3,4,5)
(2,3,5)
(1,2,4,5)

The result has to be (2,5)

What is the best way to do it to achieve best performance?

Comment: Might your arrays have duplicates?

Comment: No, arrays does not have duplicates

Comment: yes, it is dynamic. But I can assume than it usually will be less then 10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the arrays are expected to contain many different numbers  and only few present in all of them,

- pick the two smallest arrays, compute their intersection by stepping through them sequentially (like for a mergesort), O(len1 + len2)
- while not all arrays have been scanned, pick the next smallest array, and compute its intersection with the intersection of the previously handled arrays, using a sequential scan if `length(intersection)*log(length(array)) >= length(array)`, and looking up the elements of the intersection in `array` otherwise.

Worst case complexity is O(sum(lengths)), if you're lucky, you get around `k * sum(log(length))`, where `k` is the number of elements in the intersection.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

- Create one index for each array
- if for each array the element at the respective index is the same, add the element to your result list and increase each index by one
- otherwise increase the index pointing to the lowest element
- repeat until the first array is exceeded

This should also work if the arrays can contain more than one instance of a number, e.g. arrays (1,1,2,2), (2,2,3,3) would result in (2,2).

Answer (score 2):

This is what my thinking:
create one `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` it will be like `numer->hits` ;
    iterate over all array:

- if element exist in hashMap then increment count(value), ie count++;
- if element not exist then write count = 1 to value

After all you will have, number->count

```
1->1
2->3
3->2
4->2
5->3
```

So you again iterate over HashMap and print if(value==arrays.lenth)

So Space is O(N) and O(N) steps.

note hashmap's access is constant time(yahoooooo).