# Intersection of vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, data-structures, intersection

I have few vector. for eg 4

```
std::vector1 <CMyClass>;
std::vector2 <CMyClass>;
std::vector3 <CMyClass>;
std::vector4 <CMyClass>;
```

I want a resultant vector which will have the object which is present in all the vector.
For eg. if

```
Vector1 has C1, C2, C3;
Vector2 has C1, C2;
Vector3 has C1, C4;
Vector has  C1, C5;
```

I want resultant vector to have C1.

I can run loop and compare and find out the resultant vector, but I would like to know if there is any direct way of doing it.
Like some operator or data structure.

Comment: Perhaps look into [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)

Comment: Since you have more than two, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875993/efficient-set-intersection-of-a-collection-of-sets-in-c) is probably more relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sort the vectors.
2. Use [`std::set_intersection()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) three times (as many vectors you have - 1).

---

Time Complexity Analysis:

- 4 * O(nlogn) = O(nlogn)
- linear in 2 * (firstSize + secondSize) - 1
- linear in 2 * (firstSecondInterSize + thirdSize) - 1
- linear in 2 * (firstSecondThirdInterSize + fourthSize) - 1

which is bounded by O(nlogn), meaning that sorting is the bottleneck of the algorithm.

---

Full code example:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::set_intersection, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector

int main () {
  std::vector<int> first = {5,10,15,20,25};
  std::vector<int> second = {50,40,30,20,10};
  std::vector<int> third = {10,20,3,4,0};
  std::vector<int> fourth = {4,20,10,3,6};
  std::vector<int> v(first.size() + second.size() + third.size() + fourth.size());
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;

  std::sort (first.begin(),first.end());
  std::sort (second.begin(),second.end());
  std::sort (third.begin(),third.end());
  std::sort (fourth.begin(),fourth.end());

  it=std::set_intersection (first.begin(), first.end(), second.begin(), second.end(), v.begin());
  it=std::set_intersection (v.begin(), v.end(), third.begin(), third.end(), v.begin());
  it=std::set_intersection (v.begin(), v.end(), fourth.begin(), fourth.end(), v.begin());
  v.resize(it-v.begin());

  std::cout << "The intersection has " << (v.size()) << " elements: ";
  for (it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> The intersection has 2 elements:  10 20

Answer (score 0):

That's an *intersection*, not a *superset* (that would mean the union, or collection of all the elements contained in any of the four vectors).

If you can sort the vectors, the direct way is to use [`std::set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

You'll have to use it three times, getting intermediate results *A=intersection(v1,v2)* and *B=intersection(3,4)* before getting the final result from *intersection(A,B)*.

Using this [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876139/212858) will be more efficient (skipping the two intermediate containers), but does require more manual coding (and testing).

Answer (score 0):

What about this? You have to add operator<() in your class (and auxiliary operator<<()). Form std::set from each vector, then calculate intersection of these sets. Again - make vector from resulting set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class CMyClass
 {
 public:
     CMyClass(int n){_n=n;}
     ~CMyClass(){}
     bool operator<(const CMyClass a) const{return _n <a._n;}
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s,const CMyClass& a){s<<a._n;return s;}
 private:
     int _n;
 };
vector<CMyClass> find_intersect(vector<vector<CMyClass>>& vecs)
{
    vector<CMyClass> res;
    if (vecs.empty()) return res;
    set<CMyClass> S;
    for_each(vecs[0].begin(),vecs[0].end(),[&S](const CMyClass& e){S.insert(e);});
    for(auto &vec:vecs)
    {
        set<CMyClass> s,tmp;
        for_each(vec.begin(),vec.end(),[&s](const CMyClass& e){s.insert(e);});
        set_intersection(S.begin(),S.end(),s.begin(),s.end(),std::inserter(tmp,tmp.begin()));
        S=tmp;
        if (S.empty()) break;
    }
    for_each(S.begin(),S.end(),[&res](const CMyClass& e){res.push_back(e);});
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    vector<CMyClass> v1={1,2,3};
    vector<CMyClass> v2={1,2};
    vector<CMyClass> v3={1,4};
    vector<CMyClass> v4={1,5};
    vector<vector<CMyClass>> vectors;
    vectors.push_back(v1);
    vectors.push_back(v2);
    vectors.push_back(v3);
    vectors.push_back(v4);
    auto res = find_intersect(vectors);
    cout<<"[";
    for(auto &elem:res)
        cout<<elem<<",";
    cout<<"]"<<endl;
}
```

Output:
[1,]